# Deadlock when we we have dependent entities in hibernate and try to update table using multiple threads in Vertica

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, database-deadlocks

I have two java classes. `Father.java and Children.java`

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "FATHER")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    class Father implements Cloneable
    {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "father_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long fatherId;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "father_id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Children> children = new ArrayList<Children>();
    //getter and setters and public constructors 
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Children")
    class Children implements Comparable<Children>
    {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @Column(name = "children_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long child_id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "father_id")
    private long fatherId;
    //public constructors and getters and setters
    }

    public interface RelationDao{
    
    public Father update() throws Exception;
    
    }
    @Repository("relationDao")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @Transactional
    public RelationDaoImpl{
    @Override
    @Transactional("txManager")
    public Father update(Father father)
    {
    father = merge(father);
    //added retry logic as well also father is updated with a new child which is why merge
    }
    }
```

I receive the Deadlock X exception if several threads visit the same table  (entity father) to *updates* with distinct row entries, even though the records are different.

Is there any way to fix why the entire table locks up instead than just one row?
Even though I haven't updated or added anything to the code, the transaction isolation level is SERIALIZABLE.

DB system is Vertica

Comment: I see only private attributes, there is literally no code here, with this code you can do practically nothing

Comment: What does `Vertica` have to do with your question? If you don't add the SQL code generated and fired by your Java app, hardly anyone from the Vertica side will be able to give sensible info to you ..

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I've made the necessary code modifications.

Comment: The relevant mechanisms and problems aren't related to Hibernate and JPA. Instead, they depend on the specific database system, the isolation level in use, the indexes on the foreign key columns etc. Please provide this additional information.

Comment: @Codo The current transaction isolation level is SERIALIZABLE even though I havent changed or added anything as such in the code

Comment: And what about all the other information? DB system? Indexes on foreign keys? Use of MVCC?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any information on this at the moment or in the future. Only thing is sometimes i get as SERIALIZABLE or sometimes as READ COMMITTED and there are no foriegn keys either primary key is id

Comment: In this regard, MySQL behaves very differently from Oracle. So without further information, there's no point for this question. You better close it.

Comment: @Codo the DB is vertica

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with Vertica. But from their documentation (https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/Locks/AboutVerticaLocks.htm) it looks as if it does not support row level locks. If so, a single writer will lock the entire table. The improvements you can make: Lower the transaction level to READ COMMITTED to prevent readers from being blocked. Enforce a sequential order for modifications (all updates to table X must happen before updates to table Y). That way, deadlocks can be prevented. But it might not be practical with JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained here, if anyone is coming here to check why Vertica doesn’t support row level locks for updates or delete. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917383/8799862

So I used `synchronized` to perform thread-safe updates and deletes.